# QtCreator new project Qt Quick Controls vs. Qt Quick

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to create new Qt Quick project in Qt Creator and I've pressed `New project`, selected application name and location in Wizard, but then I am confused at next wizard's step (Qt Quick Component Selection), as seen in screen-shot:

[image: Qt Creator New project wizard Qt Quick Component Selection]

Which set should I select, `Qt Quick Controls 1.3`, or `Qt Quick 2.4`? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's stated in the Qt documentation :

> In the Qt Quick component set field, select the component set to use
>   for the project. The Qt Quick imports enable you to use the basic QML
>   types to create user interfaces, whereas the Qt Quick Controls provide
>   a set of ready-made controls that you can customize by using Qt Quick
>   Controls Styles

So that just specifies a primary import of modules. You can add other imports like Qt Quick Dialogs or Qt Quick Layouts later in your code.